# imagecopyresampled returning null

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code:

```
$fullImg = $_POST['img'];
$avatar_name = $log_username.md5(uniqid()).'_avatar.jpg';
$avatar_path = '../user/'.$log_username.'/';
$avatar_new = $avatar_path.$avatar_name;
$target_h = $target_w = 150;
$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];
$w = $_POST['w'];
$h = $_POST['h'];
$qual = 90;

$orig_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($fullImg);
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($target_w,$target_h);

imagecopyresampled($new_img,$orig_image,0,0,$x,$y,$target_w,$target_h,$w,$h);

imagejpeg($new_image,$avatar_new,$qual);
```

I have an error in my error_log that says:

> Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

I'm guessing it has something to do with my `$_POST['img']` variable being a full url:

```
http://domain.com/images/image.jpg
```

I have set `allow_url_fopen` to 1 in my php.ini file. i thought this might fix it.

It is only a full url because it is read by js as `var img = _('uloadedImg').src;` and despite this being set as `../images/image.jpg`, `var img = _('uloadedImg').src;` still returns a full url.

Is there a way to get the src from the image without the full url in js? Or is there something wrong with my script other than that?

Comment: $new_img != $new_image ? If you turn on error reporting you will notice these type of mistakes

Comment: You are spot on. I'm sorry to waste time on the site with such a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a type error, you are specifying `$new_img` instead of `$new_image`:

```
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($target_w,$target_h);
imagecopyresampled($new_img,$orig_image,0,0,$x,$y,$target_w,$target_h,$w,$h);
                      ^
```

Try below:

```
imagecopyresampled($new_image,$orig_image,0,0,$x,$y,$target_w,$target_h,$w,$h);
```

Comment: OMG... I think this is the universe telling me I've been at this too long today! Time for bed me thinks! Thanks :)